# unusual unexpected token in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a file call `scripts.js` and it merely do `var main = require('./main');`

and my main.js is at the same level, it has

```
module.exports = {
console.log("hello");
}
```

I do `webpack` in my terminal I got unexpected token?

Comment: because you have an object and it is invalid... It is not a function...

Comment: @epascarello must it be a function? what if I have $(function() {}()) ?

Comment: it must be a valid code first of all, function or object does not matter.

Comment: why console.log("Hello") is not valid?

Comment: Because it is inside of an object... That is not valid syntax for an object which needs name/value pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not include function executions into a javascript object (you are exporting an object), you need to export a function to achieve this

```
module.exports = function() {
   console.log("hello");
}
```

And from your file where you require the export

```
var main = require('./main')(); // Add () to execute the function that you obtained
```

**UPDATE:**

You are executing console.log() in your main.js file, think that you can simply require some script without exporting nothing, and that file should be executed. For example you can put console.log("hello") without all the module.exports thing and the code should be executed, but when you check the value of your main variable (in the file where you do the require), you probably would not find anything useful.

You can also export a function(like in the code i send before) and then execute that function later, there's many ways to aproach this, I recommend you to google a bit about how module export works and how can you use it

You can check more about module.exports here https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/, you are using it for the browser, but this examples for node should be usefull anyways

Comment: I got require is not defined error, webpack worked fine.

Comment: Can you provide the webpack config and the exact command that you execute to use webpack & how do you test the generated file?

Comment: I used this gist https://gist.github.com/learncodeacademy/25092d8f1daf5e4a6fd3 and I just do `webpack`

Comment: And finally you use the scripts.js or scripts.min.js file? Because require should be replaced by webpack, so if you are seeing an error from a require, probably you are trying to use the original file and not the generated from webpack

Comment: but why I need to call the function? `var main = require('./main')();`, I've never seen something like this.